# Adding current_page_item class using get_pages and anchor links

Tags: php, wordpress, class, anchor

I'm using the following code to add anchor links using get_pages, which is working great.

```
<?php
if ( is_post_type_archive('archive') ) {
$args = array(
   'post_type'=> 'archive',
   'parent' => 0,
               'sort_order' => ASC,
               'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
             );
$mypages = get_pages($args);
?>
<ul class="archive-list-pages">
<?php foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
?>
<li>
   <a href="#<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>"> <?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a>
</li>

<?php
}
 ?>
 </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

However, I'm trying to add 'current_page_item' class and can't figure out how to do it, I've tried adding an if statement to href as below but can't work out what I'm missing.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

```
   <li>
  <a class="<?php if ($page->ID == $page->post_name) echo 'class="current_page_item"'?>" href="#<?php  echo $page->post_name; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a>
  </li>
```

Update: Used jQuery to add active classes in the end. Seem my answer below.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with your if statement. The `ID` is numeric and the `post_name` is a string, so in essence, you're evaluating `if ( 47 == 'My 47th Post Title')`. Unless your post title is `'47'`, it will be false.

Comment: I'm trying to target the $page->post_name so that when the anchor link is clicked it adds the 'current' class.

Comment: Sorry. Your last comment makes no sense at all.

Comment: @leanda what page is the page where you want the `class=current` be added? on which links? all links? or the link you click?and when? I think you are not sure what you want. If you click on a link, you are not on that page anymore and you go to another page, and that link does not exist anymore, because you have a new page

Comment: Ok, sorry if I'm not being clear. I have a page with a menu built using the code above, the menu gets parent pages from a custom post type and jumps you up and down the page using jump anchor links. The menu gets the $page->$post_name and the targets the $post_name which is dynamically added to headings within the page, this works great.
I'm trying to add a class of 'current_page_item' when one of those jump link anchors has been clicked and is active. I'm just not sure how to target the active link in the if statement. Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, I'm not leaving the page. The menu moves you up and down the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Well your php if statement was close

```
<li>
<a class="<?php if (is_page($page->ID)) echo 'class="current_page_item"'?>" href="#<?php  echo $page->post_name; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a>
</li>
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that this might help. I used some jQuery to achieve this in the end adding an active class once the jump link had been selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.archive-list-pages a").click(function () {
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $("a.active").removeClass("static");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```